# How to format a date in vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net

I want to display my date like so in VB.NET

2008/01/22 14:23:15

How is this done in code?

This does not give me enough:  lblDate.Text = Today.Date

Comment: You have both C# & VB.Net tags, please remove one?

Comment: This blog post has a good description of how to do string formatting:
[http://idunno.org/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx](http://idunno.org/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: and if i want to place the year first like in my example?

Comment: Apologies, should be `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 9):

This should display the way you want:

```
Dim formattedDate As String = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

And see [Custom DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(VS.71).aspx) for a complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try :
Date.Now